# CSRF protection with Angular + Spring Boot + REST + JWT

Tags: angular, rest, spring-security, jwt, csrf

I am working with an Angular + Spring Boot application and I use JWT for authorization (token stored in an http only cookie), the backend is fully developed with REST services. Now I am trying to use CSRF protection with Spring Security but I don't understand how it works. A new XSRF-TOKEN is always generated for each request, but even if you change it manually or delete it, subsequent requests are always successful.

This is my code snippet regarding CSRF (i.e. what is written on all the guides):

```
http = http.cors().and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(this.getCsrfTokenRepository());
```

...

```
private CsrfTokenRepository getCsrfTokenRepository() {
    CookieCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
    tokenRepository.setCookiePath("/");
    return tokenRepository;
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. When you configure `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` with `withHttpOnlyFalse`, it means you use double submit cookie approach for CSRF validation rather than typical synchronizer pattern.

In synchronizer pattern, incoming token is matched with the one stored in session.
While with `CookieCsrfTokenRepository`, it is checked if there is cookie named CSRF_TOKEN and a header name X_XSRF_TOKEN and **if their values match**. Please note cookie name and header name may not be exact, but the point here is there is no specific value in session to be matched against.

It means if I send a token with value A or cookie with value A (A is different than the one stored in cookie sent by Spring security), request will pass because it only checks if header and cookie value are same, not the one it generated.

This is **not** a security flaw. This is [how](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#double-submit-cookie) double submit cookie approach works.

Comment: In your opinion is this approach secure enough since you can use any value just match (without encryption or other)? Can't an attacker do the same thing?

Comment: I had hoped you would read the linked document. It says that double submit cookie relies on availability of same-origin protection, that would cause no one from any other site, can inject and run the JS. Since, no one would be able to run any other JS, only your site would be able to send request header. Hence the protection.

Comment: When I say I can add cookie and header, I meant from Postman, not from browser.